# How to set breakpoint automatically in bochsrc.txt with bochsdbg?

Tags: bochs

I want to set a breakpoint at 0x7c00 when I run bochsdbg.

I don't want to type these two commands my myself everytime.

```
  b 0x7c00
  c
```

How to do it in bochsrc.txt?

Thank you~

Answer (score 4):

How about using magic breakpoint? Add `magic_break: enabled=1` to your bochsrc file, and then add `xchg bx, bx` to where you wanna set breakpoint in the asm file.

Answer (score 0):

you may create a file in same directory you are running bochs and entries like(brkfile.txt): 
pb 0x7c00
lb 0x80100000

once you start bochs you may source file by typing: 
source brkfile

Better would be to compile bochs with internal debugger if you working on bootload. Internal debugger would come in handy specifically for bootloader or osdev

Answer (score 0):

You also may write down all the command in rc-file and run Bochs as following

bochs -f .bochsrc.32.obj -dbglog $loghome/$log.log -rc ./debug.rc

The rc-file may contain your debugger commands to execute like loading symbols, setting breakpoints or watching memory locations.